# how to pass the data to other UIViewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios

I am developing a project using mvvm in swift3.And it is using without storyboard.So,how to give didSelectRowAt from tableview.

Comment: This is not a free programming service. Please show us what you have tried so far and why it failed, and please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

Consider SomeViewController as the viewcontroller you want to jump to and "someViewController" is the identifier on that viewcontroller.

In the tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath call the self.performSegueWithIdentifier

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath 
   indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someViewController", sender: 
   indexPath);
}
```

In prepareForSegue method just identify the identifier for the SomeViewController and add it as destinationViewcontroller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: 
  AnyObject!) {
  if (segue.identifier == "someViewController") {
     let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! 
     UINavigationController).topViewController as! SomeViewController
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't just copy an answer from another question. You can provide a link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016382/123632 in the comments