# How to the table cell has the Segue function in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the UITableViewController to design a view in apps in objective C. I want to the table cell has the segue function that can jump to another view controller in objective c.

How to let the table cell has the segue function in objective C?

Screen Picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHXxp.jpg)

@fazeelahamed : I try to use your method, but it also shows the error message.

Screen Picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sic6U.jpg)

My Code part:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxUbU.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiXuN.jpg)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performseguewithidentifier

Comment: when you click on Cell at that time `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method call. do segue on that method

Comment: @Nitish I remember this method needs the UI element ID. I can't control the total number of the cell.

Comment: @NiravKotecha How to do the segue method for every cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider SomeViewController as the viewcontroller you want to jump to and "someViewController" is the identifier on that viewcontroller.

In the tableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath call the self.performSegueWithIdentifier

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someViewController", sender: indexPath);
}
```

In prepareForSegue method just identify the identifier for the SomeViewController and add it as destinationViewcontroller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
if (segue.identifier == "someViewController") {
    let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! SomeViewController
    }
}
```

**In Objective-C**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: 
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"someViewController" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"someViewController"]) {
          SomeViewController *someViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
     }
}
```

Comment: I remember this coed format is swift format. I hope my project is the objective-c format. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the above answer by including it for Objective-C. Hope it helps you @DavidLin69

Comment: @DavidLin69 maybe this answer will help you

Answer (score 0):

At first add

```
#import "SecondViewController.h" (change it to in which viewcontroller you want to seague)
```

in header, then write this code under table delegates

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDENTIFIER_OF_YOUR_SECONDVIEWCONTROLLER"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I try to use your method, but it can't work. It will show the error message in Xcode. Do you have other methods? Thanks.