# How to open activity and pass variable on selection of collectionview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `collectionView` and I am using a custom cell that shows an Image and label. I am populating the view with an array. When a cell is selected, I want a new activity to open and the name of the class to be passed through.
Here is my code:

```
class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
let classes = ["English","Math","Science","Social Studies","Other","Technology"]
let class_images : [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "English")!,
    UIImage(named: "Math")!,
    UIImage(named: "Science")!,
    UIImage(named: "Social Studies")!,
    UIImage(named: "Other")!,
    UIImage(named: "Technology")!
]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  var layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 22, left: 22, bottom: 22, right: 22)
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 22
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of items
    return classes.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "class_cell", for: indexPath) as! custom_class_cell
    cell.class_name.text = classes[indexPath.item]
    cell.class_image.image = class_images[indexPath.item]
    // Configure the cell
cell.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    return cell
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 //This isn't the right code, but an example of what I want to do!
 if (indexPath=1){
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "classes")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
 //I want to pass this string to the class
 let class_name2 = "English"
 }
 else if(indexPath=2){
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
 "classes")
                self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
 //I want to pass this string to the class
 let class_name2 = "Math"
 //it keeps going through the technology cell
  }

}
```

In the `didSelectItemAt` method, there is an example of what I am trying to do, but the code isn't right. I want to do this for all cells English to Technology. Thank you in advance and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Please refer to this link. Hope this solves your query. [Collection view Segue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016382/2257055)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually a really simple solution, I just over complicated it!

```
 override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   let valueToPass = classes[indexPath.row]
```

That gets you name of each class when the cell is clicked. After that, just do the prepare for segue method.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way:
in dest controller (let's say is a DetailController instance)
you should have:

```
class DetailController...
...    var myInfo : MyInfo?
```

(MyInfo should contain ALL data You want to pass.)

and in prepare for segue:

```
    vc.myInfo = Info(class_name2)
```

in viewDidLoad populate your UI:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.detail.text = self. myInfo....
```